# Calculate month number,month name, first day of month(date) and last day of month(date) using common table expression in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

```
declare @start_date as datetime = '12/31/2014'
declare @end_date as datetime = '02/15/2015'

;with cte as (
   select 
       datename(month,@start_date) as [mnth_nm],
       month(@start_date) as [mnth_no],
       @start_date as dat,
       DATEADD(DAY, -1 * DAY(@start_date) + 1, @start_date) as [first_day],
       DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, @start_date)), DATEADD(mm, 1, @start_date)) as [last_day]
   union all
   select 
      datename(month, DateAdd(Month, 1, dat)),
      month(dat) + 1 as [mnth_no],
      DateAdd(Month, 1, dat), 
      DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [first_day]), 
      DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, dat)), 
      DATEADD(mm, 1, dat)) + 1 
   from 
      cte
   where 
      DateAdd(Month,1,dat) < @end_date
)
select 
    [mnth_nm], [mnth_no], @start_date, [first_day], [last_day] 
from 
    CTE
```

In above CTE the required output should give december, january and february month output based on my start and end date.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Sure Marc thanks for editing ...

Comment: Why is this tagged for both Oracle and SQL Server (and two different versions of SQL Server)?  The code appears to be T-SQL so I would guess that the Oracle tag should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Change the where query only:-

DateAdd(Month,0,dat)<  @end_date

Comment: For 'January' its giving month number 13 its should be 1. and last day for january and february is not correct. Can you please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
<b>Got the solution ... </b>
<p>
declare @start_date as datetime = '12/31/2014'
declare @end_date as datetime = '03/15/2015'

;with cte as (
   select 
       datename(month,@start_date) as [mnth_nm],
       month(@start_date) as [mnth_no],
       @start_date as dat,
       DATEADD(DAY, -1 * DAY(@start_date) + 1, @start_date) as [first_day],
       DATEADD(dd, -DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, @start_date)), DATEADD(mm, 1, @start_date)) as [last_day]
   union All
   select 
      datename(month, DateAdd(Month, 1, dat)),
      month(DateAdd(m,1,dat)) as [mnth_no],
      DateAdd(Month, 1, dat), 
      DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [first_day]), 
DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [first_day])) + 1, 0)) 
   from 
      cte
   where 
    DateAdd(Month,0,dat)<  @end_date
)
select 
    [mnth_nm], [mnth_no], @start_date, [first_day], [last_day] 
from 
    CTE</p>
```